# Jacoco branch coverage unable to cover else if statement

Tags: java, quarkus, junit5, rest-assured, jacoco

I have written a rest API in quarkus to convert miles to kilometer.

```java
@GET
@Path("/miles-to-kilometers")
public Response milesToKilometers(@QueryParam("value") double miles) {
    double kilometers = miles * 1.60934;
    String answer = String.format("Kilometers: %.3f", kilometers);

    int roundedKms = (int) Math.floor(kilometers);

    if (roundedKms >= 0 && roundedKms <= 10) {
        answer = answer.concat(" is below 10");
    } else if (roundedKms >= 11 && roundedKms <= 20) {
        answer = answer.concat(" is below 20");
    } else if (roundedKms >= 21 && roundedKms <= 30) {
        answer = answer.concat(" is below 30");
    } else if (roundedKms >= 31 && roundedKms <= 40) {
        answer = answer.concat(" is below 40");
    } else if (roundedKms >= 41 && roundedKms <= 50) {
        answer = answer.concat(" is below 50");
    } else if (roundedKms >= 51) {
        answer = answer.concat(" more than 50");
    }

    return Response.ok(payload, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
}
```

For the above code snippet, I've written a test case using junit

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(doubles = { 1, 0, 5.0, 15.0, 25.0, 35.0, 45.0, 55.0, 2.688, 5.645, 11.789, 15.678, 20.678, 28.211,
        35.212, 45.677 })
public void testMitoKm(double miles) {
    String url = String.format("/miles-to-kilometers=%.2f", miles);
    given()
        .when().get(url)
        .then()
        .statusCode(200)
        .body(containsString("Kilometers: "))
        .body(containsString(getExpectedMessageForMiles(miles)));
}

private String getExpectedMessageForMiles(double miles) {
    double kilometers = miles * 1.60934;
    int roundedKms = (int) Math.floor(kilometers);
    if (roundedKms >= 0 && roundedKms <= 10) {
        return " is below 10";
    } else if (roundedKms >= 11 && roundedKms <= 20) {
        return " is below 20";
    } else if (roundedKms >= 21 && roundedKms <= 30) {
        return " is below 30";
    } else if (roundedKms >= 31 && roundedKms <= 40) {
        return " is below 40";
    } else if (roundedKms >= 41 && roundedKms <= 50) {
        return " unbelievable";
    } else if (roundedKms >= 51) {
        return " is below 50";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

The if and else if branches are still not covered by the Jacoco.
Displaying that 1/4 branches are not covered.
Giving yellow warning lines over the else if statements.
How to cover all the branches for this given snippet in jacoco ?

Comment: Maybe if you simplified the logic?  For example (assuming you handle negative values correctly first) then you don't need to say ">= 31" if the preceding cases have already handled all possibilities up to and including 30.

Comment: The last else branch was never activated by the test. Add at least one negative number to test input.

Comment: Thanks @zforgo I added a negative number. Now its good.

Answer (score 0):

In @ValueSource I added a negative value -1. Now JaCoCo can able to cover all the branches

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(doubles = {-1, 1, 0, 2.688, 5.645, 11.789, 15.678, 20.678, 28.211,
        35.212, 45.677 })
public void testMitoKm(double miles) {...}
```

After add -1 in valuesource jacoco can able to cover all the else if conditions.